# linux redirect java System.out to file

Tags: java, linux, bash

I running jar via "start-stop-daemon". My code:

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
USER=root
MAIN="/usr/share/folder/jarfile.jar"
DAEMON="/usr/bin/java"
ARGS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar $MAIN"

start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --chuid "$USER" --background --make-pidfile --startas "$DAEMON" -- $ARGS
}

stop() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]
        then rm $PIDFILE
    fi
}
```

I want redirect java System.out to file. When I try this code:

```
start() {
       start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --chuid "$USER" --background --make-pidfile --startas /bin/bash -- -c "$DAEMON $ARGS  > /usr/share/folder/log.txt  2>&1"
}
```

method `stop()` does not stoped deamon.

How possibile to redirect System.out to log file?

Thanks!

Comment: In the script, you are redirecting to `/usr/share/folder/log.txt`.  Did you look at the file?

Comment: Also, you should make the comparision between 2 command lines that are the same *up to* redirection.

Comment: @devnull of couse. If i use second variant, console is redirected. But method "stop" does not stoped deamon :(

Answer (score 0):

You have just did it in the second part, please check the log in /usr/share/folder/log.txt